# Do I need to use Telerik's Kendo UI Server for ASP.NET MVC apps?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Where I work, we're about to start on a new project. To work on this new project my employer has purchased some of Telerik's Kendo UI control suites. We'll be using Kendo UI for jQuery. I just finished installing Kendo UI for jQuery. I've no experience with this, so after installing it I looked at the README file. It says, in part:

> Kendo UI server wrappers are not included in this version of Kendo UI. To access the Kendo UI server wrappers, you must purchase and download one of the following:
>
> - Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC

So, here's the ignorant, beginner's question. Do we need Kendo UI Server wrappers for developing this new app we'll write in ASP.NET MVC, or can we proceed without Kendo UI Server wrappers?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-the-kendo-ui-mvc-server-wrappers-are-and-why-you-should-be-using-them---part-1

Comment: Yes, I have. It is because of that blog that I posted my question. In fact I posted a question asking the same thing in the comments of that blog post. However, the author of that post did write it 8 years ago. He might not reply. He may no longer work for Telerik.

Comment: No it's not required. However, I agree with what is said in the link David provided: "While you can certainly write great web applications in ASP.NET MVC that leverage Kendo UI without the extensions, the extensions clearly make your development easier, faster and less prone to error."